# Save canvas as a file and putting to scrollview as a search result

Tags: basic4android

In short I would like to know how to do this:

Saving a canvas with all the output of label/edittext/views as an (image)file on sdcard.

Using a search function, it will catch this canvas and display it on a scrollview or
listview.

I hope someone out there knows the answer or having a nice example of the code.

Thanks for now,
JackD

Answer (score 0):

The following code saves the canvas bitmap to a file:

```
Dim Out As OutputStream
Out = File.OpenOutput(File.DirRootExternal, "Test.png", False)
Canvas1.Bitmap.WriteToStream(out, 100, "PNG")
Out.Close
```

You can draw the views to the canvas by using Canvas.DrawDrawable with the views background.

Not sure what you mean with the search function. You can later load this bitmap and display it on a ScrollView (with an ImageView) or ListView (with AddTwoLinesAndBitmap).

Comment: You can use File.ListFiles to find all the files in a specific folder.

Comment: Thanks Erel for your answer, I'm gonna check if this what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi Erel, 

I got: 

java.lang.NullPointerException
 
 at com.testcase.JackD.preview._btcapture_click(preview.java:296)
       \\   etc...etc.   


Do i miss something??    

note: I already have a panel with labels/imageview and button

Comment: It is better to start a new question for that. Check Project - Include Debug Information. It will give you the B4A line that raised this error.